# How to encrypt files in twisted?

Tags: python, encryption, twisted, obfuscation

I'm using twisted to create a server.
Problem is, I must protect my code. Since I don't want to publish it, I'm not really interess into obfuscation or compilation of the python code.
My problem is, my twisted application must run with root uid and a lot of people have root access to this server.
I don't care if they can read it, but I want sure they can't modify it!
What is the best solution, knowing I'm using twisted? I've seen in twistd, tapconvert and mktap that twisted can "encrypt" my code, but I didn't find any good documentation about that.
Anybody to help me?

Thanks in advance for any answer =)
Have a nice day!

/!\ EDIT:
I got another question, I've wrote my code following this part of twisted documentation: http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/application.html so I launch my server using a command like twistd -y server.py --logfile ...
Since I'm doing that, I assume I can't use software like cx_Freeze to hide my code right ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a number of problems here.

> my twisted application must run with root uid

This is bad.  If there are vulnerabilities in your application, then they will be made more serious by running as root.  You should consider finding a way to not run as root.  For example, if you only run as root so you can bind to a low numbered port, consider using [authbind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authbind) instead.

> a lot of people have root access to this server

Perhaps you should limit privileged access to those people who actually need it.  If that isn't an option, then perhaps you should at least limit access to *people you can trust*.  Someone who has root on a machine can do anything they want on that machine, and defeat any scheme you dream up.

> I don't care if they can read it, but I want sure they can't modify it!

You should ask them not to modify it, then.

> I've seen in twistd, tapconvert and mktap that twisted can "encrypt" my code, but I didn't find any good documentation about that. Anybody to help me?

You shouldn't bother trying to use the encryption features of twistd and mktap.  These don't prevent anyone from changing your code.  At best they might prevent someone from reading some of it.  As you said, this isn't even your goal.  Even if it were your goal, someone with root access will be able to decrypt these files easily, so it doesn't even help there.

If you give code to someone, expect them to be able to do anything and everything they want with it.  If you put code on a server, you are effectively giving it to everyone with root access to that server.

So, stop thinking about encryption and other technical issues and think of some other way to achieve your goals - fire the untrustworthy administrators, use an appropriate license on the code, get an actual contract, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The main reason to run my soft with root uid is because it must launch at some point other binaries which must run as root too. I'm currently working on this problem. I'm trying to remove access to the server from people I don't trust but it will take some times to achieve this. Anyway I'm interested in preventing somebody to read it, maybe it will discourage bad co-workers to modify it =) I'm also interested, for my "culture" on how the encrypt feature of twistd work. If you have any link... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no way to prevent a root user from modifying a plain text file. Root is just that, they can do anything they want with it including modifying. Why do so many people have root access to the machine anyway?

If you're concerned, you really have two options:

1. Encrypt the files in whatever way you want (I don't know if Twisted does it or how)
2. 'Compile' the code for your platform. There are a few Python compilers out there but I don't know if they work with Linux. I'm a free software guy so I want people to read and modify my code. Protecting it doesn't concern me.

I guess you do have a third option of protecting it legally with a license. But if they violate your license then there's the cost of taking them to court over it.

Not many options. Sorry.

Anthony

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My software is for internal use of my company only. The server runs FreeBSD and around 10 people got root access and yes I know this is the real problem... But the situation can't easily be changed. I asked about twisted because tapconvert, mktap and twistd got option about encrypting files but I can't find how it works.

Comment: Encrypting the data or compiling the code doesn't protect it from modification or being read in any meaningful way; this is bad advice.  The code needs to be decrypted when it's run either way, and compiled code (especially in Python) is easy to read.